# How do I bring the parent window in front of child windows in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Currently I have a root / parent qml window, which creates some child windows. It works perfectly, however I cannot bring the parent window infront of a child window. It always stays in the background of the child window. Is there a way how to change this?

The parent.qml

```
// parent.qml
Window {
     visible: true
     id: root
     ...
     childComp = Qt.createComponent("child.qml")
     childWindow = childComp.createObject(root)
     childWindow.show() 
    }
```

And the corresponding child.qml

```
// child.qml
Window {
    id: childWindow
    visible: true
...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need the windows to be siblings, not parent/child.

Comment: What about making ```color: "transparent" ``` on *child.qml* ?